# DataGridViewImageColumn Image layout doesn't work

Tags: c#, datagridview, imagelist, datagridviewimagecolumn

I'm trying to display an image on datagridview with an image column; however,
it appears stretched vertically and squished horizontally. I'm not sure what's limiting it to be displayed this way.

Grid Generation

```
            gvPackage.Columns.Clear();

            gvPackage.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            DataGridViewColumn[] cols = new DataGridViewColumn[5];
            GridColumn gc = null;

            cols[0] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            cols[0].DataPropertyName = "ID";
            cols[0].Name = "ID";
            cols[0].Visible = false;

            cols[1] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            cols[1].DataPropertyName = "iLive";
            cols[1].Name = "iLive";
            cols[1].Visible = false;

            cols[2] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            cols[2].DataPropertyName = "iExplicit";
            cols[2].Name = "iExplicit";
            cols[2].Visible = false;

            cols[3] = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            cols[3].Name = "Icon";
            cols[3].Width = 70;
            cols[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            cols[3].FillWeight = 1F;

            cols[4] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            cols[4].DataPropertyName = "sName";
            cols[4].Name = "sName";
            cols[4].Width = 216;
            cols[4].FillWeight = 50.5166F;

            gvPackage.Columns.AddRange(cols);

            List<Package> _pl = _______Manager.SHARED_RES;

            foreach (Package p in _pl)
            {
                gvPackage.Rows.Add(
                    p.ID,
                    p.iLive,
                    p.iExplicit,
                    gImageList.Images["imgNoExplicitNoLive"],
                    p.sName
                    );
            }
```

Cell Formatting:

```
 private void gvPackage_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (gvPackage.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Icon")
            {
                bool isExp = this.gvPackage.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "1";
                bool isLive = this.gvPackage.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "1";
                if (isExp && isLive)
                {
                    e.Value = gImageList.Images["imgExplicitLive"];

                }
                else
                    if (!isExp && isLive)
                    {
                        e.Value = gImageList.Images["imgNoExplicitLive"];
                    }
                    else
                        if (isExp && !isLive)
                        {
                            e.Value = gImageList.Images["imgExplicitNoLive"];
                        }
                        else
                            if (!isExp && !isLive)
                            {
                                e.Value = gImageList.Images["imgNoExplicitNoLive"];
                            }
            }
        }
```

Bad image:

[image: Incorrect image]

The source image:
[image: Source image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking the `gImageList.Imagesize`!

It's default will use square image sizes of 16x16!

Change that to the size of your `Images` **before** you load them:

```
gImageList.ImageSize = new Size(61,12);
```

Note that **all** `Images` need to have the **same** size. If they haven't you should change them; much better than the stretching the ImageList will apply!

Also note that the `Images` in an `ImageList` are **limited** to `256x256` pixels.

You may also want to check if you are happy with its `ColorDepth = Depth8Bit`

Obviously your `Column/Cell` needs to provide enough space as well!

Comment: thank you. That's exactly it... my ImageList is 22x22. I totally missed that. What is the optimal way of storing images of different sizes? Should I abandon ImageList and use some other structure?

Comment: Well it depends. For many sizes I guess you should add them as __resources__. For only 2 or 3 sizes 2 or 3 Imagelists are ok, imo. But if all images are supposed to be displayed in the same column I would make them all the same size..